# WxPython custom styled controls

Tags: python, controls, wxpython

I'd need to make a new style for buttons and text entry controls. It should look something like
[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, try to look up the `wx.Frame` `style` property `wx.FRAME_SHAPED` here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxframe.html#wxframe
I think it only applies to `wx.Frame` but maybe you can bind an event to mouse clicks inside the custom-shaped frame.